# Dynamic Sheet Referencing in Excel, incrementing months

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel workbook with mutiple sheets. The sheets generally following the naming format like this: Jan23, Feb23, Mar23....Jan24, Feb24, and so on (mmmyy).

I also have a final sheet at the end, where I want to reference the individual month's sheets. Lets say in that last sheet, I want a row of data that references cell A1 from each month.

I could do this manually by typing out `='Jan23'!A1`, `='Feb23'!A1`, etc. But is there a way I can automate this, without having to type in every one individually?

Answer (score 0):

In a new Excel you can use `HSTACK` function with a 3-D reference, e.g.

```
=HSTACK('Jan23:Dec24'!A1)
```

where you specify names of the first and last sheets.
If you want to refer all sheets but the current you can also use a shortcut:

```
=HSTACK('*'!A1)
```

But these two formulas are static, so if you add a new sheet at the end of months, formulas will not include it. However you can create an empty sheet called 'Last' and place it before your final sheet. And new worksheets should be added before that 'Last'. And then you can use the variant:

```
=HSTACK('Jan23:Last'!A1)
```

or that with an asterisk for all sheets.